# Why is the complexity of merging M sorted arrays linear time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, merge

Suppose we want to perform external sort and have M number of blocks sorted, where each block contains k comparable items such that n = Mk. k in this case also refers to the maximum number of items you can fit into memory for sorting, and n is the total number of items to sort.

Then using the merge function in merge sort, each element will have to be compared against all other elements from other blocks, which gives me O(M) comparison for one element. Since we have to do this for all elements, we will have O(M * Mk) = O(M^2 * k) = O(nM) time complexity.

This seems to be linear at first, but suppose in the worst case we can only fit 1 item into memory. So we have M=n blocks, and the time complexity is O(n^2) directly. How does the merging gives you linear time in external sort?

Also, in the case where k = 1, how is the sorting even feasible when there cannot  be any comparisons done?

Comment: When the first item from each array is compared, the next items can be compared using binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Make priority queue based? for example, on [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), fill it with current items (or their indexes) from every block, and extract top item at every step.

Extracting takes `O(log(M))` per output element, so full merging is `O(n*log(M))`

For your artificial example: `O(n*log(n))`

Comment: Will indexes work when they don't convey the value of the elements? How could this make for a comparison? I don't think we can achieve better than linear time for extracting the minimum, since we need to at least iterate through every element at least once to know whether it is the minimum to be extracted. And then we have to repeat the process of getting a new set of integers to find the minimum again, as we can't reuse the old set.

Comment: For example, `Block[num][pos]` refers to pos-th  item of num-th  block. How to compare them - depends on implementation. Concerning minimum extracting - read about binary heap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap